# Ckeditor se inicia dos veces al abrir modal

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

tengo una funcion JS para abrir un modal, Codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#eventosanalisis').on('click', '#editar_evento', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    });
    var filaactual = $(this).closest("tr");
    var id = filaactual.find("td:eq(0)").text();
    document.getElementById("nombremodalevento").innerHTML = filaactual.find("td:eq(1)").text();
    document.getElementById("fechamodalevento").innerHTML = filaactual.find("td:eq(2)").text();
    document.getElementById("municipiomodalevento").innerHTML = filaactual.find("td:eq(4)").text();
    document.getElementById("sectormodalevento").innerHTML = filaactual.find("td:eq(5)").text();
    editor.setData(filaactual.find("td:eq(3)").text());  
    UIkit.modal("#modal-editar", {bgclose: false, keyboard:true}).show();    
});
//limpiar ckeditor al cerrar modal
    $('#modal-editar').on('hidden',function (e) {
        CKEDITOR.remove(editor);
    });
```

});

Al momento de seleccionar una fila en mi tabla funciona bien, pero si cierro el modal y vuelvo a seleccionar la misma fila el editor se muestra dos veces

Comment: Creo que esta linea `CKEDITOR.remove(editor);` no esta funcionando. La variable `editor` no parece estar inicializada en ningún lugar. Sacala de `$('#eventosanalisis').on('click', ....`

Comment: Intenté declarar `editor` como variable global pero no funciona, igual saqúe la linea `CKEDITOR.remove(editor);` de la funcion onclick y no funciona sigue mostrando doble el editor

Comment: Tal vez sea porque no destruyes la instancia del editor, hay que eliminarla y despues construirla otra ves, lo que haría es crear una función con todo lo que tienes del editor y con el clic llamar tantas veces sea necesario, así como eliminar la instancia

Comment: cambié a `CKEDITOR.instance[editor].destroy();` y tampoco funciona

Comment: listo solo hice lo siguiente `if (CKEDITOR.instances['editor1']) {
            CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].destroy();
            }
        editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');`